# Presenting Split View Controller hides the tabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have four tabs in the `TabBarController` which is my home controller. Then I have a `tableView` in the first VC. When I use `didSelect` method to call `splitViewController` using present, it will come on top of tab bars at the bottom.
How would I bring the `splitViewController` above my First VC but behind the tabBar at the bottom? I tried to put the `splitViewController` inside normal `ViewController`, it looks ugly and I do not want to do that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but if you want to put a `UIViewController` on top of another `UIViewController`, while visibly staying in the same tab of a `UITabBarController`, the standard approach would be to use a `UINavigationController`:

Instead of adding the ViewController containing your tableView directly to the TabBarController, try wrapping in in a `UINavigationController` first, e.g. by creating one with `UINavigationController(rootViewController: <UIViewController>)`.

Then, on `didSelect` inside your TableView-ViewController, instead of using `present` on the TableView-ViewController itself, use `pushViewController(<UIViewController>, animated: <Bool>)` on the TableView-ViewController's optional `.navigationController` property.

If you don't like the appearance of the `UINavigationController`'s navigation bar, you can customize or even hide it completely (but that's a different topic).